# javascript xml parser undefined check

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

Im parsing an xml file with javascript like this :

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0];
```

Everything works as expected, except that some times when i dont have an entry "Name" in the xml it shows this error :

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0] is undefined
```

which crash my website.
Is there any way to check if xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0]  has a value and then continue to parse this value to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
if(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name") != 'undefined' && xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0] != 'undefined'){
// your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
check this code:-

if (typeof(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0]) != "undefined" && xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0] != null){

//ur code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) like this:

```
if (typeof xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0] !== 'undefined') {
  // not undefined
}
```